# Leaflet 1.0 release

Tags: leaflet

I was listening Future of Leaflet talk: http://www.confreaks.com/videos/4665-jsgeo2014-future-of-leaflet and I'm really looking forward for 1.0 release. Are there any news on estimated release date?

Comment: This would almost certainly be better asked on IRC (http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=leaflet), the a leaflet mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/leaflet-js) or if you want to help it get there faster, consider the range of options for getting involved: bottom of http://leafletjs.com/ provides options...

Comment: It looks like things have started moving https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3124

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't have a fixed release date, but will be released "when done". The plan was "in October", but has already shifted. You can track [this](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/milestones/1.0-beta1) and [this](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/milestones/1.0-beta) milestones for 1.0-beta version, but the number of issues there is too high to be optimistic about this year release of 1.0-final.